# No signature tool if sending embedded signing with a template using ducusign API

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

I am developing an application that let users sign the documents from my app by using DocuSign API. I was following these two links (Embedded Signing https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding & Using Template https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/templates), but I have got 2 problems.

The first one is the embedded signing gets sent but still an email sent to the user which is not what I want. The second one is if I use a template in the embedded signing, no signature tool shows up on the template.

Regarding the second issue, I tried to add signature tool from my sandbox template tab, also tried to use code to control the signature, but all didn't work.

Does anyone have similar issues, any help appreciated.

```
private EnvelopeDefinition makeEnvelope(String signerEmail, String signerName) throws IOException {
    EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envelopeDefinition.setTemplatesUri("/templates/0426d2ca-8c40-4d02-bc42-1f64f21fa29f");
    // my template Id
    envelopeDefinition.setTemplateId("0426d2ca-8c40-4d02-bc42-1f64f21fa29f");

    TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
    signer1.setEmail(signerEmail);
    signer1.setName(signerName);
    signer1.setRoleName("signer");

    SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere();
    signHere1.setAnchorString("/sn1/");
    signHere1.setAnchorUnits("pixels");
    signHere1.setAnchorYOffset("20");
    signHere1.setAnchorXOffset("10");

    // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
    Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs();
    signer1Tabs.setSignHereTabs(Arrays.asList(signHere1));
    signer1.setTabs(signer1Tabs);


    envelopeDefinition.setTemplateRoles(Arrays.asList(signer1));
    envelopeDefinition.setStatus("sent");

    return envelopeDefinition;
}
```

Comment: Zhi li, I have a doubt regarding this embedded signin

Comment: @Gen go ahead. what doubt you have there

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, my issue is I am getting error with the above code, I have resolved the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding:

> The first one is the embedded signing gets sent but still an email sent to the user which is not what I want.

Embedded signing is enabled for a recipient signer if the `clientUserId` is set for the recipient. If it is set, then email will not be sent to the signer if, in the Admin Tool, the SIGNING AND SENDING > Signing Settings screen has the option `Suppress emails to embedded signers` checked.
[image]

Re:

> The second one is if I use a template in the embedded signing, no signature tool shows up on the template.

The DocuSign Web tool can be used to create templates, but the recipients in the templates (the `roles`) will not have the clientUserId set.

I think you can set the clientUserId when you set the role's other attributes (name, email, etc) when you use the template but I haven't tried it. If that doesn't work, please ask a new, specific, question of "How do I add clientUserId attribute to a template role."

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for your reply. Yeah, you are right, I have tried your suggestion to add a clientUserId when sending an embedded signing with a template, works fine. Thank you very much!